# GLTF file not well positioned by Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs, gltf

I want to display a hurricane (big isosurface object) in Cesium. For this I converted an OBJ file with longitude, latitude, altitude columns for each vertex of the isosurface representing the hurricane, in a new OBJ  file reprojected in ECEF (Earth Centered) projection.
So the final OBJ file contains now X,Y,Z for each vertex instead of longitude, latitude, altitude. After final reformat by obj2gltf, I try to display the GLTF "hurricane" file in Cesium.JS using the code below:

```
console.log('loading hurricane.gltf';
var mymodel = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
                         url : 'data/hurricane.gltf',
                         modelMatrix : Cesium.Matrix4.IDENTITY,
                         asynchronous: false
                   }));
```

I can see my hurricane on the earth, but not at the good position. I suspect a problem of matrix. IDENTITY matrix seems not to be the good one. I could try to make a new matrix but I can't find enough informations about the axes orientation used by Cesium.
I verified the X,Y,Z ECEF coordinates, they are good. Does anyone already meet this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If your glTF model origin is at the center of the hurricane, you can place it using a Cesium Entity, something like this:

```
// Longitude degrees, Latitude degrees, height in meters
var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-123.0744619, 44.0503706, height);
var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0);
var pitch = 0;
var roll = 0;
var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll);
var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr);

var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Hurricane',
    position : position,
    orientation : orientation,
    model : {
        uri : 'data/hurricane.gltf'
    }
});
viewer.trackedEntity = entity;
```

There are more complete working demos of this on [Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=3D%20Models.html).

But, if your hurricane is visible on the surface of the Earth using the identity matrix, that likely means that the origin of that model is nowhere near the center of the hurricane.  You may need to edit the glTF file, to make sure that the model is centered on its own origin, and does not have some fixed Earth location pre-baked into the model's internal transformations.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the model origin must be the earth center because its coordinates are ECEF. I can see the model (hurricane) on the earth surface, but it is badly positioned. That's why I suppose it's a matrix problem.

Comment: No, glTF models, like all GPU graphics, use 32-bit floats for vertex positions.  Starting from the center of the Earth yields barely 1-meter precision for individual vertices at the surface.  The hurricane shape will "rattle around" as the camera moves close enough to see individual meters, because the origin is 6.3 million meters away.  You need an origin near the hurricane, to display correctly.

Comment: Cesium uses 64-bit math for the relationship from the camera to the origin of the model.  But individual verts use only 32-bit to describe the relationship from the origin to any specific point.  So the origin of any model should ideally be the center of the model, or someplace within the model.

Comment: Thanks again EmacKey. I gave up the ECEF projection and I finally used a EastNorthUp projection centered at the eye of the hurricane. Now the position of the entity is OK. Thanks !!!